# Identifying (non exact) duplicates from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, search-engine

Is there any tools for identifying, and merging non exact duplicates in MySQL tables?

I have a large data set with many duplicates like:

```
1348,  Auto Motors, 12 Long Road, etc
48264, Auto Mtors,  12 Log Road,  etc
82743, Ato Motoers, 12 Lng Road,  etc
83821, Auto Motors, 13 Long Road, etc
92743, Auto Motors, 11 Long Road, etc
```

There are many tables needed to be merged like:

- Companies
- Addresses
- Phone Numbers
- Employees

There is about 100,000 rows, and 30-40 columns to match on each row (joined tables).

So, anyone know of a tool for sorting this out? I already have MySQL, PHP installed. I have/can use(d) MongoDB, and Solr before if they would help. And I am open to installing other software if needed.

---

Alternatively what kind of queries should I run if I cannot find a tool to handle this.

A simple `find all duplicates` wont work because they are not exact.

Doing wildcard like searches would be extremely slow for all the different combinations I would need to try.

Using a [`Oliver`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) or [`Levenshtein`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) [(MySQL)](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php) may work, and there is too much data to pull into PHP (also probably extremely slow).

Comment: Are you looking to clean the data as well, or just find the numbers once? If you have some time to cleanse, you might be able to use the MySQL [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) to match for relevance (though it would take some time) and allow you to clean your existing data - then you would be able to run some quick comparisons.

Comment: @Fluffeh just identifying the data is the key step, I can build a merge process if I can identify it. If there is a tool that can merge it for me, great! Full text search is not really *that* good, it especially has trouble searching for place and company names, as they aren't always real words.

Comment: Did you take a look to MySQL operator [SOUNDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like)?

Comment: You'd need to decide what constitutes a typo - _Ato Motors_ or _Log Road_ are probably both permissible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have data that requires massaging. I don't think this is something you can do entirely in sql.

[Google Refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/) is a *great* tool for massaging.  I would load the data in Refine first, clean it up, then import into your relational database.

Comment: I'd take care using any 3rd party apis when "massaging" data, unless their TOS specifically states they "don't", Google may store the data being massaged for their own access.

Comment: Google Refine is an offline tool, not a web service. Data is not sent to Google.

Answer (score 2):

> Doing wildcard like searches would be extremely slow for all the different combinations I would need to try.
>
> Using a Oliver or Levenshtein (MySQL) may work, and there is too much data to pull into PHP (also probably extremely slow).

You state this as if it were facts, but that is exactly what I would suggest. E.g. load one row into php. Then loop over all other rows, matching with various algorithms that you feel are appropriate (Levenshtein or perhaps your own list of stopwords etc.). It'll take a while to run through, but this is presumably something you can do as a one-off task or at least a periodical one (say, once per day)